# How to include the `.local` in domain extensions automatically included in search by Macos DNS

Tags: networking, macos, dns

When attempting to ping my localhost with the fully qualified local domain name:

```
 $ping mtvl151c46e97.local
PING mtvl151c46e97.local (172.28.50.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.28.50.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.093 ms
64 bytes from 172.28.50.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
```

However, attempting the ping without the `.local` does not work:

```
15:35:19/hadoop $ping mtvl151c46e97
ping: cannot resolve mtvl151c46e97: Unknown host
```

This is true even after having updated the `System Preferences | Network | Advanced | DNS | Search Domains`:

[image]

So what else needs to be done?  I am on `Sierra`.

Comment: Do not use .local or mdns/zeroconf.

Comment: @atype  That is a company policy / setup not within my control. This appears to common: two large companies I have last worked for have all macs configured this way.